# Trim all letter instead first

Tags: php, xml, trim

```
$out.= "<Initials>".$customer[firstname]." ".$customer[lastname]."</Initials>\n";
```

how to trim letter of the string and get only first letter in XML flie any help please

Comment: This isn't going to cut it for any help..

Comment: @artur please mark my answer as the correct one, if it helped you and answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$oldString = "hello";
echo substr($oldString, 0, 1);
```

Output:

```
h
```

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly. If I'm wrong, give an input->output example.

Comment: And please google next time a bit, I couldn't see any research effort in your question.